# multiple dynamic countdown timers vue js on laravel

Tags: vuejs2, laravel-5.6

I would like to have a countdown timer for each of my auction items, these auctions can and will be loaded dynamically.

Ideally **{{ auction.total_bids }}** would be the countdown, this will need to be reset to a value i can set on a click event.

My code so far, is as followed:

```
<template>
<div>
    <h1>Live Auctions</h1>
    <ul class="row">
        <li class="col-lg-4" v-for="(auction, key, index) in auctions" :key="auction.id">
            <span>{{ auction.name }} ({{ auction.id }})</span><br />
            <span ref="bitTime">{{ auction.bid_time }}</span><br />
            <span ref="totalBids">{{ auction.total_bids }}</span><br />
            <span ref="user">{{ auction.username }}</span><br />
            <button ref="newBid" @click="bidOnThis(auction.id, key)">Bid on this item</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props : {
        date : {
            type: Number,
            coerce: str => Math.trunc(Date.parse(str) / 1000)
        }
    },
    data() {
        return {
            auctions: [],
            newBid: '',
            totalBids: '',
            user: []
        };
    },
    created() {
        axios.get('/auctions').then(result => {
            this.auctions = result.data
        });
        axios.get('/getuser').then(result => {
            this.user = result.data;
        });
        window.Echo.channel('auction').listen('AuctionUpdated', ({ auction, username, key }) => {
            this.$refs.totalBids[key].innerHTML = parseInt(this.$refs.totalBids[key].innerHTML) + 1 ;
            this.$refs.user[key].innerHTML = username ;
        });
    },
    methods: {
        bidOnThis(id, key) {
            axios.post('/auctions', { id: id, key: key });
            this.$refs.totalBids[key].innerHTML = parseInt(this.$refs.totalBids[key].innerHTML) + 1 ;
            this.$refs.user[key].innerHTML = this.user.username ;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Can you provide a specific question?

Comment: sorry, i thought i had, i need a countdown timer that counts down a time from say 2 mins to 0, then do something, but i need this for each auction in auctions which are generated dynamically on the fly. the ref bitTime is where the value will be that counts down for each item

Comment: So what are you asking? How to implement the timer?

Comment: yes, i found multiple guides on how to do it for a single timer, but nothing for multiple dynamic countdown timers

Comment: @The-WebGuy did you getting countdown time from server if yes use computed method in that get result from server   computed: {
    total() {
       axios result  set to v-model
      },}

Comment: can you give example please?

Comment: I am only getting the total time from the server, the countdown for each element, i assumed would be controlled by Vue. or rather i will update the end time on the server and ensure the countdown is aligned with that

Comment: I am working on similar project, I was wondering how you fixed this ?

Comment: I would have to dig out the code, if you still need an answer, i will share